# "He got angry really quick(ly)"

Tags: grammar

Do I need an adjective or adverb here? I usually use fast so that there is no visible difference but I hear people say things like "Lets do this real quick" all kinds of colloquial stuff so I am not certain whether "really quickly" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example "quick" modifies the verb "got" so the adverb "quickly" is correct.

However, that being said, "quick" is often used colloquially as an adverb.  Since you use "got" instead of "became", "He got angry real quick" is natural colloquial speech.

If you want to write the same thing more "formally", you'd instead say something like, "He quickly became angry."

Comment: OED thinks _quick_ is an adverb, and so did Shakespeare! _"Such discourse, as...shall make it / Goe quicke away."_ (The Tempest.) Better notify the editors of their boo-boo!

Comment: But you wouldn't say, "He 'quick' became angry."  So there's still some nuance.

Comment: Indeed not. I wouldn't say it, and it's not colloquial; word order matters, and the word is more commonly used as an adverb, and of course Mrs. Grundy would have rapped my knuckles for writing "He got angry quick!" Yet, it _is_ an adverb.